# Apache mod_speling PHP framework

Tags: apache, mod-speling

I have Apache’s mod_speling module enabled and can’t get lowercase URLs to work properly. This is running on Ubuntu.

Example: `localhost/controller`

The file name is `Controller.php`.

It works when I type in `localhost/Controller`.

Is there any way to set up Apache to use the lowercase version?

My configuration for mod_speling:

```
CheckSpelling On
```

Comment: From the docs: _“[…] by comparing each document name in the requested directory against the requested document name __without regard to case__, and allowing __up to one misspelling__ (character insertion / omission / transposition or wrong character)”_ – so I think it’s not actually mod_speling making the correction from `Controller` to `Controller.php` for you here, because that’s more than __one__ misspelling; it think that’s rather MultiViews that is resonsible for _that_.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for that...Sucks that it only allows up to one misspelling. I ended up using symlinks until I switch to good ole nginx